# How to tell if remote tty is waiting for input?

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, tk-toolkit, putty

Previously, I have used Tk/Expect along with plink (PuTTY) to automate remote shell operations. However, Expect sometimes fails if different shells have different prompts, or if prompt characters appear in non-prompt shell output (!)

I want to know if there is a way to tell if a remote shell is expecting input, either through plink, or some third party library. I am okay programming at the sockets layer if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to reliably detect a shell prompt at the level you're working at. Some alternative options might be:

- Always run commands which will print some recognizable output when they complete -- e.g, `doSomething ; echo uniqueStringThatMeansThatWeAreDone` -- then search for that string.
- Make your automation script set the prompt to something it'll recognize when it logs in. If you don't know what shell you're using, just `exec` the one you want.
- Use a SSH library which can execute commands directly, rather than trying to script a shell. I'm not familiar with what's available in Tcl, but Perl has `Net::SSH::Perl`, which will let you do things like:

  ```
  my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new("remotehost");
  $ssh->login("user", "pass");
  my $output = $ssh->cmd("doSomething");
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am going to research how Net::SSH::Perl is implemented, not to reinvent the wheel, but that is the knowledge I am interested in.

Comment: You probably don't want to try to recreate Net::SSH::Perl yourself -- it's a reasonably complete implementation of an SSH client in Perl. Not easy. :)

Comment: Set the prompt to a fresh UUID; the likelihood of that cropping up by accident on the other side is laughably miniscule.